# Проблема с инициализацией массива byte (android)

Tags: android

Изучая пример кода столкнулся с проблемой, а именно там была строка:

byte[] decrpt = new byte;

Все бы хорошо, но студия выдает ошибку, как в новой студии переделать эту строку под нужный формат.

Comment: Хотелось бы взглянуть на код, ради интересна :)

Answer (score 0):

Подробная статья  о массивах:

В вашем случае: byte[] a = new byte[Кол-во];

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/array.php

Comment: это то понятно, что обычно массивы задаются так, но почему-то в примере скобок с количеством ячеек не было, поэтому и появляется вопрос. Вот сайт откуда брал пример: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/security/des-with-cbc-example/
Есть подозрение, что так задавалось, чтобы память выделилась уже после, когда в массив передастся определенная информация

Comment: Возможно,  вы правы, думаю , либо автор имел ввиду что то на подобии этого:   byte[] a;, а позднее происходит инициализация этого массива,  этого  либо забыл написать [Кол-во]; либо это внедренный синтаксис библиотек, но это наврятли конечно, хотя вполне может быть

Comment: Нашел не плохие примеры: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=lambdalab-mirror/jdk8u-jdk/jdk8u-jdk-master/test/com/sun/crypto/provider/Cipher/AEAD/SameBuffer.java  , https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javax.crypto.Cipher&method=update  -  4 пример, в 1 ссылке функция doTestWithSameArrays вызывает функцию  runGCMWithSameArray, где и вызывается update() и перед тем, как закинуть массив в runGCMWithSameArray, происходит объявление и инициализация массива  byte[] AAD_and_text = Helper.generateBytes(outputBufSize);

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка автора, и возможно, но очень маловероятно, измененная библиотека

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться)

Comment: Не за что ) Обращайтесь )